# double condition checking in where using linq to populate datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, datagrid, where-clause

I have a little problem populating a datagrid via select list on LINQ.
the thing is, i need these two filters to get the right list, and those filters are:
"ventilador" `(PK = cod_ventilador)` and "procesador" `(PK = cod_procesador)` must not exist on "Overclock" `(PK = id)`
the database is pretty simple: both `ventilador` and `procesador` are products (Productos) and, when you do an overclock using one of each (*?) you'll add a new Overclock which have the PK of both items...
So here is the code i've tried

```
{

    var pregunta1 = db.OverClock.Select(x => x.cod_procesador).Distinct().ToList();
    var pregunta2 = db.OverClock.Select(x => x.cod_ventilador).Distinct().ToList();

    dgSinOver.ItemsSource =
        db.Producto
            .Where(x=>x.Procesador!=pregunta1 && x.Ventilador!=pregunta2)
            .Select(x => x.marcar)
            .Distinct()
            .ToList()
        ;

}
```

it's clearly impossible to compare a single `cod_procesador(PK on Productos)` with a list of codigos `(PK on overclock)`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `Contains` method:

```
dgSinOver.ItemsSource = db.Producto.Where(x=>!pregunta1.Contains(x.Procesador) && !pregunta2.Contains(x.Ventilador)).Select(x => x.marcar).Distinct().ToList();
```

(that is, if I understood your question correctly).